# Is “Elle est âgée de 24 ans” correct?

Tags: expressions

*Elle est âgée de 24 ans.*
Is this sentence correct? If yes, when do I use this sentence and when: *Elle a 24 ans*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this sentence is correct.

> She is 24 years old.
>
> She is 24.

*Agée de* is a more formal, administrative way to state her age.

Answer (score 1):

The change here is between the verb "avoir" and "être"

When you say:

> j'ai 24 ans.

And you say

> je suis âgé de 24 ans.

It is the same sentence and correct